# react native splash screen programatically

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to manage splash screen programatically in react native. Is there any way get splash screen image from api or internal storage. Also I want to  change app name and app icon programmatically. For example after change picker item change app can be change splash screen, app name and icon.

Answer (score 1):

Before I used the package to make the splash screen at react native.
You can reference this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find how can i get image uri from api.

Answer (score 1):

Just fetch Your app splash screen content from api and save name and image in local storage, and when app opens in splash screen check if data saved in local load from local else get it from server and save in local too,

You can also use **Codepush in react-native** for live updates in your app

Comment: Thank you. I am trying right now. I hope this will resolve my problem.